# Where is the "point of infinity" for elliptic curve over finite fields?

Tags: elliptic-curves

This might be a dumb question, but I can't find the answer. Everywhere I see people say elliptic curve is this set of points plus a point of infinity on a finite field. Where is that point of infinity? Because finite field is finite, is the point of infinity an actual point or just an "imaginary" one? In real space, the point of infinity is clear.

Comment: The elliptic curve consists of points in projective plane. Projective planes have "points at infinity". It has nothing to do with how many elements the field has. You get one point at infinity for each direction of a line in affine space.

Comment: Even in the traditional viewing of an elliptic curve as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the point at infinity is not a 'point' that sits anywhere on the plane. Even the metaphor that it sits at "positive infinity" is simply a useful "lie." The point has "only" a clear definition in projective space. [The 'only' here because one can, of course, use a change of coordinates to put place the point at infinity in the affine plane. There is a nice discussion in either Silverman, Washington, Husemoller, or Lozano-Robledo, which I do not recall - or all of them!]

Comment: ['Point at infinity' is an affine or projective point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4108496/338051)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks! If we have a 2d prime field with r=2, there are only 4 points: (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1). Wonder how many points at infinity are there in this space? My intuition is that there is one on the right and one on the left, and due to mod they are the same point at infinity. In the same way there is a point at infinity along the vertical direction. Wonder if this right or completely wrong?

Comment: @JustinZhang Projective plane consists of triples $[a:b:c]$, not all zero, with two such triples "the same" if they are scalar multiples of each other. Those with $c=1$ correspond to the affine points. Those with $c=0$ are points at infinity. For the field with 2 elements, you have 7 points total, four of which are affine, three are at infinity. They correspond to the "horizontal", "vertical", and "diagonal" directions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah, got it, thanks! So the three infinity points are [ 1: 0: 0 ] (horizontal), [ 0 : 1 : 0 ] (vertical), and  [ 0 : 0 : 0 ] and [ 1 : 1 : 0 ] are the same diagonal point at infinity.  If given an elliptic curve like  y^2 = x^3 + x + 1 which has two points in this space: [ 0 : 1 : 1 ] and [ 1 : 1 : 1 ], wonder how can I find out which point at infinity should be included to make it a group?

Comment: @JustinZhang $[0:0:0]$ is not a valid projective point.  Elliptic curves in projective space have homogeneous equations in $X,Y,Z$, so yours would be $Y^2Z = X^3+ XZ^2 +Z^3$. The only point at infinity is $[0:1:0]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the explanation! Do you mean that the point [ 0 : 1 : 0 ] covers all directions, including horizontal, vertical and diagonal?  You mentioned that there are three points at infinity for field with 2 elements, and the only point at infinity is [ 0 : 1 : 0 ]. Just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: @JustinZhang Of course I do **NOT** mean such a thing. That is the only point at infinity *on the elliptic curve curve with the given equation*. It's not about directions, it's about the equation.

Comment: @JustinZhang: Please read [this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13767/742) to understand how the "points at infinity" work for the usual, complex/real affine plane. It's the exact same idea for finite fields.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks I got it, and thanks for the link. I see that the three points at infinity in the space are defined by three 3D lines:   [0:0:0]-[1:0:0],  [0:0:0]-[1:1:0],  [0:0:0]-[0:1:0], and among them the only one satisfying the elliptic curve equation is the last one.

Comment: @JustinZhang For the **third** time, $[0:0:0]$ is **NOT A POINT**. Projective points must have at least one nonzero entry.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin isn't each projective point a line in 3D space? I probably wrote the notation wrong. Should be (0,0,0) instead of [0:0:0]. In your other article you mentioned sending lasers from the origin to various points. I meant to say the origin using (0,0,0). I didn't mean that (0,0,0) is a projective point. The key thing here is that everything makes sense to me once I got the geometric intuition. I meant to say that the three projective points are three lines (or directions) in the 3D space, and they are alone the direction of origin-(0,1,0), origin-(1,0,0), origin-(1,1,0).

Comment: @JustinZhang The notation $[a:b:c]$ (square brackets, colon) represents a point in Projective plane. $[a:b:c]=[x:y:z]$ if there exists a nonzero scalar $k$ such that $a=kx$, $b=ky$, and $c=kz$. At least one coordinate must be nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you need to understand what "projective plane" is.  It's easier to work over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ to start with, because that's what we are used to. So let's start there, we'll move to finite fields in a minute.

Let's start with the affine real plane. That's what you know from analytic geometry, the "cartesian plane". We can identify it with the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. An algebraic curve is the set of all points $(a,b)$ that satisfy some polynomial equation $f(x,y)=0$.

In affine space things don't always go "generically". For example, two distinct lines "usually" intersect at a single point... but they may be parallel and never intersect. This can be solved by going to "projective plane."

[Here is a post in which I gave a way to think about projective plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13767/742). But projective plane is identified with *triples* of points $(a,b,c)$, *not all zero*, where we identify two points $(a,b,c)$ and $(r,s,t)$ if there exists a (nonzero) number $\lambda$ such that $(a,b,c)=(\lambda r,\lambda s,\lambda t)$. This corresponds to identifying points with "lines through the origin in $3$-space", as I do in the post linked to above.

The equivalence class of a point $(a,b,c)$ in the projective plane is traditionally denoted something like $[a:b:c]$.

Projective plane can be "covered" with three standard copies of the affine plane: all points with $c\neq 0$ correspond to a point of the form $[a:b:1]$, and we can think of these points as the points of the affine plane $\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$. All points with $b\neq 0$ can be uniquely represented as a point $[a:1:c]$, and they "look" like an affine plane. And the points with $a\neq 0$ which can be represented as $[1:b:c]$.

So, the points $[a:b:1]$ can be thought of as being in the "affine part" of the projective plane. There are other points, namely all points of the form $[a:b:0]$, with $a$ and $b$ not equal to $0$.  All but one of them can be represented as $[1:m:0]$, and following with the analogy of "lines through the origin" in the other post, we can think of this point as being added "at infinity in the direction of lines of slope $m$". The final "point at infinity"  is the point $[0:1:0]$, which we can think of as being the point "added at infinity in the vertical direction".

Now, because a point $[a:b:c]$ and the point $[2a:2b:2c]$ are "the same projective point", we cannot define curves on projective space using any old polynomial: we run into problems. For example, the line $x+y-1=0$ would seem to include the point $[0:1:0]$, but not the point $[0:2:0]$, *even though they are the same point in the projective plane*.

So for projective space we need polynomials with the property that $p(a,b,c)=0$ if and only if $p(\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c)=0$ for any nonzero constant $\lambda$. These are called [*homogeneous polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial), and they are polynomials in which every monomial has the same total degree.

To "projectivize" an affine curve $p(x,y)=0$, we find the highest total degree monomial, and we add enough powers of $z$ to every *other* monomial to get a homogeneous one, $P(x,y,z)$. For example, the polynomial
$$p(x,y) = y^2 -x^3-2x-xy$$
has highest total degree $3$, so it is projectivized by adding powers of $z$ to every monomial other than $x^3$ to make them of degree $3$:
$$P(X,Y,Z) = Y^2Z - X^3 - 2XZ^2 - XYZ.$$
Note that "affine part" of the curve $P(X,Y,Z)=0$, that is, the one with $z=1$, is exactly the same as the affine curve $p(x,y)=0$.

In projective space, things go much better than in affine space; for example, the intersection of two distinct projective lines is *always* a single point: we do not need to worry about "parallel lines not intersecting". More generally, over the complex numbers we have [Bezout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem#Statement) that says that the intersection of a curve given by a polynomial of degree $n$ and a curve given by a polynomial of degree $m$ always consists of $nm$ points (counting multiplicities to deal with things like "tangential intersections" and the like).

Now, a (projective) elliptic curve is a projective curve defined by a polynomial of the form
$$P(X,Y,Z) = Y^2Z + a_1XYZ + a_3YZ^2 -X^3 - a_2X^2Z-a_4XZ^2+a_6Z^3$$
and we look for projective points with $P(X,Y,Z)=0$. You can also think of it as the projective points $[a:b:c]$ that satisfy the equation
$$Y^2Z + a_1XYZ + a_3YZ^2 = X^3 + a_2X^2Z+a_4XZ^2+a_6Z^3.\tag{1}$$
(In characteristics different from $2$ and $3$, a change of variables can bring into a form with $a_1=a_3=0$, yielding the more familiar form.)
For such a curve, the affine part consists of solutions to the equation
$$y^2 + a_1xy + a_3y = x^3 + a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6.$$
In addition, we also need to check the points "at infinity" (that is, with $Z=0$) that satisfy this equation. Going back to equation $(1)$, we see that if $Z=0$, then we just get the equation $0=X^3$, so it consists of the points $[0:b:0]$. Since $b\neq 0$, all of these points are represented by $[0:1:0]$. This is the only "point at infinity" that lies on the projective curve defined by equation $(1)$. If we keep our idea that points at infinity represent "directions" on the affine plane then this point is the point in "the vertical direction".

---

The same thing happens over any finite field $k$. We have the affine $k$-plane
$$\mathbb{A}^2_k\colon \{(a,b)\mid a,b\in k\},$$
and we have the projective $k$-plane
$$\mathbb{P}^2_k = \{ [a:b:c]\mid a,b,c\in k\text{ not all zero}\},$$
where $[a:b:c]=[r:s:t]$ if and only if there exists $\lambda\in k$, $\lambda\neq 0$, such that $[a,b,c]=[\lambda r:\lambda s:\lambda t]$. An elliptic curve is a projective curve given by equation $(1)$, but where now $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ take values in $k$, not $\mathbb{R}$. And just as before, the only non-affine point that lies in the curve is the projective point $[0:1:0]$. So the projective elliptic curve has exactly one "point at infinity", namely $[0:1:0]$.

Note that in a field with $q$ elements, affine plane has $k^2$ points; "straight lines" (solutions to equations of the form $ax+by=0$ with $a,b$ not both zero) have $q$ points.

Projective $k$-plane has $q^3-1$ triples, but each triple has $q-1$ "names" corresponding to the $q-1$ possible values of $\lambda\neq 0$; so you have $(q^3-1)/(q-1) = q^2+q+1$ projective points. Straight lines (solutions to equations of the form $aX+bY=0$) have $q+1$ points: the $q$ points with $Z=1$, plus a single point with $Z=0$.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I have a few questions related to the finite fields discussion near the end. For (3−1)/(−1)=2++1, are we assuming that the "lines" don't share points with each other? In a field with q=4, for example, seems like the following two lines would share a point:  [0:0:1] - [0:0:2] - [0:0:3], and [0:2:1] - [0:0:2] - [0:2:3].   At the same time, for the point  [0:1:2], the line seems to be: [0:1:2] - [0:2:0] - [0:3:2]. Is this valid? because it has a point with z=0.       Also do you mean that affine plane has q^2 points?

Comment: @JustinZhang That number counts **projective points**, not lines. The field with four elements does **NOT** contain $2$ or $3$. What you wrote is both nonsense, and again shows that you are not actually reading what I wrote carefully.

Comment: @JustinZhang Honestly, I think this is way above your current capabilities. Go learn what real and complex projective space are first, because you clearly think you know but do not in fact know what it is. And learn what a finite field actually is, because again, you clearly do not really know. You aren't ready to think about elliptic curves over finite fields.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example of a projective line $X = \mathbb P^1(k)$ over a field $k$.  Formally, $X$ consists of all equivalence classes of points $(x_0,x_1) \in k \times k$, where $(x_0, x_1)$ is equivalent to $(y_0, y_1)$ if there is a constant $0 \neq c \in k$ such that $cx_0 = y_0$ and $cx_1 = y_1$.

There is a canonical injective mapping of $k$ into $X$ where we send $x \in k$ to the equivalence class of $(x,1)$.  So we may think of $k$ as a subset of $X$.  Then $X$ is the disjoint union of this copy of $k$ and one more point $\infty$, namely the class of $(1,0)$.  This is the point at infinity.

This intuition makes sense in the case where $k = \mathbb R$.  Indeed, for $x \in \mathbb R$ large, the point $(x,1)$ is equivalent to $(1, \frac{1}{x})$, which approaches the point $\infty$ as $x$ tends to infinity.  Even though this intuition breaks down when $k$ is a finite field, the algebraic construction of $\mathbb P^1(k)$ and its point at infinity may be carried out in exactly the same way.